# Nz function: Why can't I use an OR operator inside this function?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I want to use `Nz()` to check if a field on my form is blank. If it *is* blank, I want to use a longer expression.

`Nz([Forms]![MainForm]![Combo298],'"A" Or "B" Or "C"')`

However, this doesn't return anything. I know that the values `A`, `B`, and `C` will definitely return values on their own, so I figured that maybe it was the `Or` operator causing the problem here. I also tried inverting the quotation marks like so:

`Nz([Forms]![MainForm]![Combo298],"'A' Or 'B' Or 'C'")`

...but this didn't return any results either. How do I make it so that if the field on the form is blank, I can use an expression in its place?

To be clear, the ultimate goal here is to run a query based on some criteria. If the user fills in the textbox on the form, then he is saying that he wants to use that value as the criteria for one of the fields in the query. ***BUT*** if that field is blank, then the query should return all possible values for that specific field in the query.

Comment: Edit your question and show the entire logic where the `NZ()` is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you essentially saying:

> When Combo298 is null, return an A, B or C value

Functions only return 1 value, so you have to specify the conditions under which 1 value will be returned over another.

I.e. if it can only return 1 value, why would it return A and not B, why would it return B and not C? You haven't specified why it would return 1 value over another so it can't return anything.

Comment: I interpreted "'A' Or 'B' Or 'C'" as one value, thinking of it like (A Or B Or C). If the field was null, then the function should output this string.

Comment: How can I accomplish my goal then? While I was waiting I also tried 

   `IIF(
 (Nz([Forms]![MainForm]![Combo298],0))=0,
 "Like 'A' Or Like 'B' Or Like 'C'",
 999999
 )` but this didn't return anything either...

Comment: I think your initial question here is starting to branch in to 2nd one. Can I recommend you accept an answer on this question since it relates specifically to why you can't use the `Nz` function in the way you were trying. You can then create a new question that describes what you're trying to achieve (perhaps with some screenshots of your form/textbox setup and any relevant VBA/sql). This be tidier and will hopefully get you the answer you're looking for. Feel free to add a link in a reply comment here to your new question and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I figured it out, but thanks! I accepted this as the answer!

Comment: Actually, I've just realized I've misunderstood what you were after. It would be better for the site if you un-accepted my answer so I can delete it and not confuse others that might look at this in the future (don't worry, my feelings won't be hurt).